# How to associate work items with builds in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

When I check in my code using VS 2015 and VSTS Online with Git, I can associate a work item with the comment I am applying to my commit.

I can see the comment in the associated changes area on the build summary page and the fact that it's related but the category above - "Associated work items" always "No associated work items found for this build".

This is causing a problem because i'd like to follow this tutorial and associate work items with builds but the script never finds anything.

http://www.neovolve.com/2016/10/25/linking-work-items-to-vsts-vnext-builds/

I have also tried placing the bug work item in various states such as Resolved and Closed before i start the build, but I get the same output:

[image: Work item associated with commit, but no work items shown.]

Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VSO/VSTS, if you associate a work item with a commit and push it to remote, when you execute a build, VSO will automatically associate the work item. Detail steps as below:

1. Commit changes and associate with a work item. There are two ways: A. add # in comment; B. click + for related work items and then input work item id.

[image]
[image]

2. Push changes.
3. Execute a build and then find the associate work item.
   [image]

Comment: Mariana - This is way I am doing it already and they don't show up under "associated work items", only under associated changes.  Further investigation revealed that if I create a new development branch and then associate on checkin, it spots them? Do I always need to branch first?

Comment: No, it’s suitable for all branches.